# Pass in Delimited String to Access Query as Parameter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to pass in a string to an Access query that has a parameter "companyType" . The sql is "where companyType in ([forms]![formname].[fieldname])"

This works fine with one value but for string e.g "CompanyType1","CompanyType2" it does not work.

I know the in operator needs to have each element in quotes if the data type for that field is a Short Text or Long text type. I have tried wrapping them in single quotes also to no avail.

When I hard code the values in the query e.g "in ('CompanyType1','CompanyType2')" query returns rows so I believe it is something with escaping the quotes but not exactly sure.

Comment: If the form choice is both  companies I build the string in the vba code :   companyList = "'Company1','Company2'"  I have tried single and double quotes but same result.

Comment: post the query and how you are passing the values.

Comment: This is the end of the query : I set the a hidden value in Vba which holds either "Company1" or  "'Company1','Company2'"  second option will not work , tried wrapping with single qoutes aswell
WHERE (((tblAllocationReservation.companyType) In ([forms]![frmRevenueByMonth]![txtHiddenCompanyType].[Value])) 
AND ((DatePart("yyyy",[reservationDate]))=[forms]![frmRevenueByMonth]![cmbYear]));

Comment: It would contain either a single value e.g "Company1"  which I do not touch if it is a single Company if it is both companies then I build a string  e.g   'Company1' , 'Company2'  and set the hidden form value as that.

Comment: I thought just creating a delimited list of values in quotes for strings would suffice.  Maybe the comma in the string is being ignored by Access ?

Comment: The db engine can only treat `[forms]![frmRevenueByMonth]![txtHiddenCompanyType]` as a single value, so `IN ([forms]![frmRevenueByMonth]![txtHiddenCompanyType])` will never be interpreted as a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to put this into an access query as a parameter; However you could build the query in vba:

```
dim qry as new QueryDef
qry.SQL = _
    "SELECT some_column, ... " & _
    "FROM some_table [INNER JOIN ...] " & _
    "WHERE CompanyType IN (" & [list] & ")"
qry.Execute
```